# Using VBA in Excel to see if I have permission to open the file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file in the system that is breaking my code. When I try to open the file via VBA or by simply opening the file through the file system, I get this error. "You are not authorized to access this spreadsheet."

I was wondering if there is a way to use VBA to check the file permissions before attempting to open the file.

Comment: I'll be interested to see any answers to this. Only thing that jumps to mind is turning off alerts Application.DisplayAlerts = False before opening which might stop it jamming. or might not...

Comment: You should be able to check by inspecting the `objfile.attributes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
'Open that might fail
On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number > 0 Then
  Call MsgBox("Open failed because " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly)
  Exit Sub
End If

' If get here, file was opened successfully
```

Comment: I have but it still will not get past the "'Open that might fail" line. I know I don't have access to see that specific file, but for now I'm just looking for a way to handle the error so that my code will run to completion.

Comment: I do not understand.  This is the purpose of `On Error Resume Next` and it has never failed for me.  Are you being rejected by the Windows file access system or by something more exotic?

Comment: At this point, I think its the windows file access system. I think I need to speak with the admin, and try to get rights to access the files.